# Cannot access correct scope within controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am trying to dynamically build a form based on data returned from the server. In this instance, I do not have my store in the `<PROJECT NAME>/store` folder. I have it in `<PROJECT NAME>/store/admin`. It is defined like this:

```
Ext.define('APP.store.admin.TaskOption', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
autoLoad: false,
storeId: 'adminTasksOptions',
model: 'APP.model.admin.TaskOption',
sorters: [
    { property: 'order', direction: 'ASC' }
]
});
```

Please notice the `storeId`.

Now in my controller, I tried this in the `init` method, but it did not work (ie: it did not call the `taskOptionsLoaded`  method.

```
      Ext.create('APP.store.admin.TaskOption');

      this.getAdminTasksOptionStore().on({
          scope: this,
          load : this.taskOptionsLoaded
      });
```

Also note, that when I did a break point and checked, `this.getAdminTaskOptionStore` returned the correct store. I am guessing that is happening because I am putting the store in a sub folder? Not sure, but instead of reorganizing folder structure and putting them all in the `store` folder (I have a ton of stores; large project), I am trying to find a solution so I can keep files organized so it is easy for the next guy.

So now I have tried this, and this doesn't work either. This is being executed in a method in the same controller.

```
Ext.getStore('adminTasksOptions').load(
        {'params' : {'t_id' : this.selectedTaskTemplate},
        callback: function(store, records, success) {
            this.taskOptionsLoaded(store, records, success);
        }
    },this);
```

When I breakpoint on the `this.taskOptionsLoaded` line, it is within the store scope, not the controller (`this`) scope.

What is the cleanest way to add a load callback in a store with it's own `storeId`, and execute a method within the scope of the controller?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller had a config `stores: ['AdminTasksOptionStore']`, it would generate a getter called `getAdminTasksOptionStore()`.

The fact your `storeId` is `adminTasksOptions` doesn't mean ExtJS will generate getters in a controller; you can, however, do `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('adminTasksOptions')`.

You'd need to have in your controller:

```
stores: ['TaskOption'],
```

And then in your controller you'll have the getter `getTaskOptionStore()`.

With regards to your load scope, you are using wrong variables, it should really be:

```
Ext.getStore('adminTasksOptions').load({
    scope: this,
    params: {'t_id' : this.selectedTaskTemplate},
    callback: function(store, records, success) {
        this.taskOptionsLoaded(store, records, success);
    }
});
```

Comment: As a side comment (and a matter of style), I'll be a bit more attentive with plurals - is it TaskOption or TasksOptions? If the store represent what options a task might have, I'd say it is correct to call it `TaskOptions`.

Comment: Fixing scope in my `load` function worked. Thanks! I had this set in my controller: `stores: ['admin.TaskOption'],`. Based on how I named my store, should it be `AdminTasksOption` or `TaskOption`? You had it listed two different ways. I use the store manager if I have two separate instances of the same store, but mostly try and use the getter.

Comment: Yes I agree on the naming too. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work `stores: ['AdminTaskOption'],`. It tried to load `/js/app/store/AdminTaskOption` when the correct path is `/js/app/store/admin/TaskOption`. I can never get the setup right when using subfolders. Which is why I have been using storeId's on any store in a subfolder, then using `Ext.getStore();`

Comment: OK I had this correct the first time `stores: ['admin.TaskOption'],`. `this.getAdminTaskOptionStore()` returns the correct store. Adding a listener like I did originally didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using `on()` function wrong. Try this:

```
this.getAdminTasksOptionStore().on(
  'load', // event
  this.taskOptionsLoaded, // handler
  this // scope
);
```